# Return None instead of False

Tags: python

I have this code that should return false at the end of the function if one of the condition isn't met, but the output keeps saying None, why so ?

```
def check_largest_and_smallest():
    case1 = largest_and_smallest(17, 1, 6)
    case2 = largest_and_smallest(1, 16, 6)
    case3 = largest_and_smallest(1, 1, 2)
    case4 = largest_and_smallest(1, 1, 1)
    case5 = largest_and_smallest(-3, -4, 0)
    if case1 == (17, 1):
        if case2 == (17, 1):
            if case3 == (2, 1):
                if case4 == (1, 1):
                    if case5 == (0, -4):
                        return True
    else:
        return False
```

The `largest_and_smallest` function is:

```
def largest_and_smallest(num1, num2, num3):


    largest = None
    smallest = None

    if (num1 >= num2) and (num1 >= num3):
        if num2 <= num3:
            largest = num1
            smallest = num2
        else:
            largest = num1
            smallest = num3
    elif (num2 >= num1) and (num2 >= num3):
        if num1 <= num3:
            largest = num2
            smallest = num1
        else:
            largest = num2
            smallest = num3
    elif (num3 >= num1) and (num3 >= num2):
        if num1 <= num2:
            largest = num3
            smallest = num1
        else:
            largest = num3
            smallest = num2

    return largest, smallest
```

Comment: Please fix your indentation.

Comment: There is a ```max``` and ```min``` function.

Comment: Can you tell me what you wanted to do in that "if case" ladder?

Comment: Are you not allowed to use built in ```max``` and ```min```? That ```largest_and_smallest``` function is just horrible.

Comment: The if case ladder is to return True only if all the cases are met, else if just one case isn't met it returns False

Comment: Yes I do know about the min and max function but I just can't use it.

Comment: I ran your code (with fixed indentation levels), and it returned True for me, not None.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is due to the use of `else`: as soon as the first `if` statement is checked, there's no `else` for the other situations, so the function simply returns `None`.

```
    case1 == (17, 1)
    case2 == (16, 1)

    if case1 == (17, 1):
        if case2 == (17, 1):
        # here case2 doesn't match, but there's no corresponding else!
    else:
        return False
```

A simple fix is to just return False without any `else`:

```
    if case1 == (17, 1):
        if case2 == (17, 1):
            if case3 == (2, 1):
                if case4 == (1, 1):
                    if case5 == (0, -4):
                        return True
    return False
```

Or, even better, use [`all(iterable)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) which checks all iterable items and returns `False` *as soon as one of them is not `True`*, meaning that the function will *stop* evaluating the following items whenever that happens:

```
    return all((case1 == (17, 1), case2 == (17, 1), case3 == (2, 1),
        case4 == (1, 1), case5 == (0, -4)))
```

Answer (score 2):

At a glance, for me, the indentation for check_largest_and_smallest() is not correct. Then, you should not use else, just return in the end will satisfy your intended logic.

```
def check_largest_and_smallest():
    case1 = largest_and_smallest(17, 1, 6)
    case2 = largest_and_smallest(1, 17, 6)
    case3 = largest_and_smallest(1, 1, 2)
    case4 = largest_and_smallest(1, 1, 1)
    case5 = largest_and_smallest(-3, -4, 0)
    if case1 == (17, 1):
        if case2 == (17, 1):
            if case3 == (2, 1):
                if case4 == (1, 1):
                    if case5 == (0, -4):
                        return True

    return False

def largest_and_smallest(num1, num2, num3):
    """
    Takes 3 numbers as arguments and returns
    the largest number and smallest number among them.
    """
    largest = None
    smallest = None

    if (num1 >= num2) and (num1 >= num3):
        if num2 <= num3:
            largest = num1
            smallest = num2
        else:
            largest = num1
            smallest = num3
    elif (num2 >= num1) and (num2 >= num3):
        if num1 <= num3:
            largest = num2
            smallest = num1
        else:
            largest = num2
            smallest = num3
    elif (num3 >= num1) and (num3 >= num2):
        if num1 <= num2:
            largest = num3
            smallest = num1
        else:
            largest = num3
            smallest = num2

    return largest, smallest


check_largest_and_smallest()
```

Comment: For me, the "if" ladder does not look good approach. How if we flatten it with "and"s? Please see my answer fo reference.

Comment: Yeah, use `and` is a better way. but I want to reveal the usage of else here.

Answer (score 0):

Consider what happens if `case1` is true but `case2` isn't.

Assuming that `if` ladder indentation is what you intend, you're only returning false if `case1` isn't true, but if `case1` is true and any of the other cases are false, your code returns nothing.

Comment: So should I put an else return False for every case ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if case1 == (17, 1) and case2 == (17, 1) \
      and case3 == (2, 1) \
      and case4 == (1, 1) \
      and case5 == (0, -4):
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Can't have more than 79 characters on a line but thanks

Answer (score 0):

For the minimum/maximum function, try something along the lines of:

```
def minmax(*x):
    return min(x),max(x)
```

In any case, you can always write

```
a < b < c
```

instead of

```
a<b and b<c
```

Comment: Read the comments